# What's the best way to serialize data in a language-independent binary format?

Tags: c, language-agnostic, serialization, asn.1

I'm looking into a mechanism for serialize data to be passed over a socket or shared-memory in a language-independent mechanism.  I'm reluctant to use XML since this data is going to be very structured, and encoding/decoding speed is vital.  Having a good C API that's liberally licensed is important, but ideally there should be support for a ton of other languages.  I've looked at [google's protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) and [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1).  Am I on the right track?  Is there something better?  Should I just implement my own packed structure and not look for some standard?

Comment: might want to see [performant-entity-serialization-bson-vs-messagepack-vs-json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355497/performant-entity-serialization-bson-vs-messagepack-vs-json) as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given your requirements, I would go with Google Protocol Buffers. It sounds like it's ideally suited to your application.

Comment: The problem I have with Protocol Buffers is that the C interface is positively awful.  I'm leaning towards asn1c at the moment.

Comment: Five years later, there are a number of good C interfaces for protocol buffers, so I'm marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider XDR. It has an [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4506). I've used it and never had any performance problems with it.  It was used in ONC RPC and has an and comes with a tool called rpcgen. It is also easy to create a generator yourself when you just want to serialize data (which is what I ended up doing for portability reasons, took me half a day).
There is an open source C implementation, but it can already be in a system library, so you wouldn't need the sources.

ASN.1 always seemed a bit baroque to me, but depending on your actual needs might be more appropriate, since there are some limitations to XDR.

Comment: I agree Sun XDR works well for all the platforms and OS we have used it on.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to throw in ASN.1 into this mix.  ASN.1 is a format standard, but there's libraries for most languages, and the C interface via [asn1c](http://lionet.info/asn1c/) is much cleaner than the [C interface for protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/).

Comment: Erlang has a superb support for ASN.1! It is very easy to use, and it is really well-documented. Read more [here](https://erlang.org/doc/apps/asn1/) ([PDF](https://erlang.org/doc/apps/asn1/asn1.pdf)). Documentation for the asn1ct module can be found [here](https://erlang.org/doc/man/asn1ct.html).

Answer (score 2):

JSON is really my favorite for this kind of stuff. I have no prior experience with binary stuff in it though. Please post your results if you are planning on using JSON!

Comment: I'm unfortunately going to have to rule JSON out due to the parsing overhead.  I'm really looking for formats that store the data in binary that does not have to be parsed.

Comment: You may be overestimating overhead -- well-written JSON parser is pretty darn efficient; and not all binary parser are well written (meaning sometimes they are slower). So I would first measure performance of alternatives instead of assuming you know the answer.

Comment: Update from my side: I've just done JSON with binary content, by manually base64 encoding the binary blobs. It works pretty well!

Answer (score 2):

[Thrift](http://developers.facebook.com/thrift/) is a binary format created by Facebook.  [Here's a comparison](http://stuartsierra.com/2008/07/10/thrift-vs-protocol-buffers) with google protocol buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/doc/hessian-serialization.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Binary XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_XML) but it seems not stabilized yet. The article I link to gives a bunch of links which might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [SNAC/TLV](http://iserverd.khstu.ru/oscar/basic.html) which is used by AOL in it's Oscar/AIM protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [Muscle](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/index.html). While it does quite a bit, it serializes to a binary format.

Answer (score 0):

Few Thing's you need to Consider

```
1. Storage
2. Encoding Style (1 byte 2 byte)
3. TLV standards
```

ASN.1 Parser is the good for binary represenations the best part is ASN.1 is a well-established technology that is widely used both within ITU-T and outside of it. The notation is supported by a number of software vendors.